# Studio styles almost never work visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

Every time I download a studio style from http://studiostyl.es/ it never looks the same as what is on the website. I have Resharper installed and disabled the colour highlighting but that still isn't working.. Is there anyone else that knows how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most of those styles on http://studiostyl.es/ are for VS2010 I think. Plus Resharper introduces quite a few of its own colour settings that may override the Visual Studio ones.

Try the [Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) extension to change the colours.